# Gcc Emacs under 22.04: libotf0 missing

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, emacs

My `emacs` executable points to version 28 installed from source following [these instructions](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GccEmacs#h5o-2), and works as expected under 21.10. Upon moving to 22.04, running `emacs` returns the following:

```
libotf.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Indeed, it is not available:

```
ll /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libotf.so*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1MB Mar 24 13:14 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libotf.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1MB Mar 24 13:14 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libotf.so.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1MB Mar 24 13:14 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libotf.so
```

After searching in the available packages for 22.04, it seems `libotf0` is no longer included, although `libotf1` is.

I thus simply changed the name of the library:

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libotf.so.{1,0}
```

and `emacs` seems to be running correctly. Is there a more robust way to deal with this kind of issue?

Comment: I forked a repo that builds emacs with pgtk and nativecomp for ubuntu 22.04. You can download the .deb [here in the "Artifacts" section](https://github.com/Xceno/emacs-gcc-pgtk/actions/runs/2582029131)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a workable hack to me, and I don't see anything wrong with running Emacs 28.1 the way you have it installed in Ubuntu 22.04. If you run into problems with your Emacs 28.1 in Ubuntu 22.04 you can install Emacs 28.1 as a snap package with the following command:

```
sudo snap install emacs --classic
```

Installing snap packages are a user-friendly way of getting the latest versions of many popular open source applications in Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was hoping there was some way to require ```libotf1``` instead of ```libotf0``` directly during configuration/compilation. Shouldn't ```emacs``` sort this automatically, depending on the available library versions? Why should it required specifically ```libotf0``` if it works just as well with a newer version?

Comment: As a side comment, I do not know why the name changed, given that, from ```21.04``` to ```22.04``` we went from [```0.9.13-7build1```](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/libotf0) to [```0.9.16-3build1```](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libotf1).

Comment: I don't know the answers to specific questions about packaging and version numbering decisions that were made by the Emacs package maintainers. Installing open source packages in macOS is normally done by homebrew package manager. Every package is the latest version. Download size is huge - 10 times the size of what it is in Ubuntu is not uncommon. Ubuntu is very friendly about download sizes compared to macOS, but the cost is that we have to cut and fit to prevent Ubuntu from wasting precious disk space. Ubuntu's motto is "Linux for human brings".

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Emacs build to exclude libotf

```
./configure --without-libotf
```

I found that from https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=emacs-git